# HTML 5 - Geolocation : position.coords.speed never come back to zero

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation

I'm using Geolocation :

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {maximumAge:0,enableHighAccuracy:true});

   var speed_convert = position.coords.speed;

  speed_convert = speed_convert * 3.6;
  speed_convert = Math.round(speed_convert);
```

When I used my application in my car the speed never come back to 0 km/h.

There are any more parameters to set ?

Thank you

Comment: Someone have an idea ?

Comment: What platform/OS version/device are you testing on? Cordova only receives the data from the GPS hardware on the device. Some devices use interpolation/smoothing to iron out the innate unreliability of accuracy in the GPS system and this can lead to side effects, such as slow ramping up/down of reported speed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm using an iPhone 6

Comment: Someone have an idea ?

Answer (score -1):

Change this,

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {maximumAge:0,enableHighAccuracy:true});
```

To this,

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {maximumAge:0,enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout=1000});
```

And have a good life!